# PHP special symlink usage

Tags: php, linux, symlink

I have the following test structure:

/www/index.php

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/linked/linked.php');
```

/www/linked/ which is a symlink to /symlinkedfolder/

/symlinkedfolder/linked.php

```
<?php
echo __FILE__;
```

The output for this script is:

```
/symlinkedfolder/linked.php
```

Is there any way/technique with PHP or Apache or Linux which would make symlink behave not symlink instead like a normal filesystem folder/file?
I need that my example give back the following output:

```
/www/linked/linked.php
```

(But in real it would be still a symlinked file which originally located in its original folder)

**UPDATE #1**

We are working with version control system and we would like to keep the checked out folder in a global folder and we would like to symlink each folders to its proper path in the actual platform(Joomla or WordPress etc...). It would allow us to only update and commit from one folder, but still refresh every platform with a single update. (This could work until we not use FILE or DIR or any related things what symlink can mix up.)

Answer (score 0):

It’s a pain. As [the official PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) explains:

> The full path and filename of the file. If used inside an include, the
>   name of the included file is returned. Since PHP 4.0.2, **FILE**
>   always contains an absolute path with symlinks resolved whereas in
>   older versions it contained relative path under some circumstances.

Which is a pain.  This is why I have decided it’s best to set a base path explicitly [as I explain here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690706/site-root-relative-path-doesnt-work/23691113#23691113).  So in your case you would set:

```
$BASE_PATH = '/www/';
```

And then your `require_once` would be like this:

```
require($BASE_PATH . '/linked/linked.php');
```

This [question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090723/how-to-get-the-relative-directory-no-matter-from-where-its-included-in-php) is similar to yours and recommends using `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` but in my experience, that setting can change radically between server to server for odd reasons. Which is why I have defaulted to the `$BASE_PATH` method when I code. You set it once, forget it & no worries.

Comment: We are working with version control system and we would like to keep the checked out folder in a global folder and we would like to symlink each folders to its proper path in the actual platform(Joomla or WordPress etc...). It would allow us to only update and commit from one folder, but still refresh every platform with a single update. (This could work until we not use __FILE__ or __DIR__ or any related things what symlink can mix up.)

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question. No, we do not use capistrano. Also we are not symlinking as it is not working for us. This is why I'm searching for solution :) If I could solve the symlinking issue, then we would be on a good path... but no luck yet.